# Choosing what Iphone app must open one url schema

Tags: iphone, url-scheme

I'm able to open a url scheme with my apps. However i can have more that one app with the same
url scheme registered so i would like let user choose the default app for the scheme.

I need to use the same scheme for all my apps. Now by default iphone uses the last app installed that can open the schema.

Have you same idea to solve my problem? 
Do you know if is possible inside an app choose itself as default to open a url scheme? 
I can't find the possibility to do this in generale setting of Iphone.

Thanks you

Comment: why do you need to use the same scheme for all the apps?

Comment: because i have multiple apps, each can open the url however exist an app that is the best for each url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported. Here is a note from Apple documentation.

> If your URL type includes a scheme
>   that is identical to one defined by
>   Apple, the Apple-provided application
>   is launched instead of your
>   application. If multiple third-party
>   applications register to handle the
>   same URL scheme, it is undefined as to
>   which of the applications is picked to
>   handle URLs of that type.

[Implementing Standard Application Behaviors](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html)

A possible solution would be to have your apps connect to the your server to get a list of your apps and their supported URL schemes. You can present that list to the user and the user can select the default app.